# How should we handle duplicate questions (with answers) that affect search results?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

A consider the following scale of scenarios:

1. Duplicate question, no answers
2. Duplicate question, repeated answers but little effort
3. Duplicate question, same answers but with a lot of effort shown
4. Duplicate question, fresh answers that do different things (and work)

Our current solution on Ask Ubuntu is to close all of these. 3 and 4 might get merged or reverse-duped (closing the older question) depending on the quality  of the new question and answers. Either way, closing feels right and fair (nobody loses reputation from it).

But my question is what should we be doing when a closed duplicate is interfering with search traffic? One example is ["remove Ubuntu put Windows back"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=remove+Ubuntu+put+Windows+back). That SERP is actually pretty decent (we feature in the top 3 with the first being our canonical question) but [add "completely" to the start](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=completely+remove+Ubuntu+put+Windows+back) and the others float to the top.

Both [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301302/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on-my-computer) [duplicates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370328/how-to-completely-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back) have answers and I think that is stopping an automatic redirect. If the answers were dirt, I'd delete them. If they were great, I'd merge... But these are just *meh*. Somewhere around 2.5 on the scale above, neither are wrong but somebody has spent time writing them.

That wasn't the best example but it's the one I'm faced with today. We've had instances in the past where we've "fixed" search priority by deleting answers or merging and people complained about heavy-handedness. And I can sort of understand. For a beginner user, losing 30 reputation if we deleted a +3 or even just 15 (if we merged their accepted answer over) is fairly serious.

It's not just the users at risk here. If we decide to merge to protect as much rep as possible, we can end up with questions that have dozens of duplicate answers. That feels just as wrong.

Is there another, better way of dealing with duplicates and search results that I'm not aware of? Is there another way of making a duplicate question transparent to Google without penalising the people who spent time answering it?

If there isn't could there be? Something like a mod-only tag that forces people coming from Google to be redirected? to the duplicate?

Comment: Kind of a hacky work around, but if the best duplicate isn't showing up for the most common search phrases then maybe try editing the best question's title a bit so it show up higher in the results?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The canonical questions' titles are usually pretty decent. It's often the more organic duplicate titles that Google is preferring in some cases. Eg ["I want to completely remove Ubuntu and reinstall Windows"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=I+want+to+completely+remove+Ubuntu+and+reinstall+Windows). There's no way to make one question cater to every nuance so to do what you're suggesting would actually mean running around making the duplicates worse and less organic. I don't think that's desirable but I appreciate the idea!